# How to disable the emoji keyboard in iOS 7?

Tags: ios, emoji

I wanted to disable the emoji keyboard programmatically. please let me know how can i do that ?

I tried using following code,

```
NSMutableDictionary *dict = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithContentsOfFile:@"/private/var/mobile/Library/Preferences/com.apple.Preferences.plist"];
[dict setObject:[NSNumber numberWithBool:NO] forKey:@"KeyboardEmojiEverywhere"];
```

But no luck ... :(

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can simply set the property keyboardType of the UITextField or UITextView to UIKeyboardTypeASCIICapable. This disables the Emoji Keyboard for this UI element.

This may not work in chinese how ever we have a workaround for it too :

```
- (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string
{
    if (IS_OS_7_OR_LATER) {
        if ([textField isFirstResponder]) {
            if ([[[textField textInputMode] primaryLanguage] isEqualToString:@"emoji"] || ![[textField textInputMode] primaryLanguage]) { // In fact, in iOS7, '[[textField textInputMode] primaryLanguage]' is nil
                return NO;
            }
        }
    } else {
        if ([[[UITextInputMode currentInputMode] primaryLanguage] isEqualToString:@"emoji"] ) {
            return NO;
        }
    }

    return YES;
}
```

User wont be able to type any emoji icon.

Comment: If we use UIKeyboardTypeASCIICapable , multilanguage support can not be possible :(. I wanted to support multi language but emoji should be disabled.

Comment: currentInputMode is depraceted in ios 7.

Answer (score 2):

Though The Question is super old, 
I was Facing the same problem and was able to resolve it by the time this page loaded by this small trick :

> **Simply Select Numbers and Punctuations in Interface Builder Xcode 8.2.1**

[image]

**Output is No Emoji Keyboard =D**

[image]

I'm sure it'll help Someone =)

Answer (score 1):

The accepted answer works good, however currentInputMode is deprecated in iOS 7. Instead you could use textInputMode as stated in [this SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26868358/1472337):

```
+(BOOL)isEmojiInput:(UITextView)aTextView
{
    return [aTextView textInputMode] == nil;
}
```