# Can't find keyplane that supports type 10 for keyboard iPhone-Portrait-Emoji

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, keyboard, swift2

I make `UISearchController` with google search engine. When I tried to search a smile in `UISearchBar` and I got error **Can't find keyplane that supports type 10 for keyboard iPhone-Portrait-Emoji; using 2871905771_Portrait_iPhone-Emoji-Keyboard_Letters** and after I got another error **fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value**.
`UISearchBar` keyboard code

```
 controllerSearch.searchBar.spellCheckingType = UITextSpellCheckingType.Yes
 controllerSearch.searchBar.autocapitalizationType = UITextAutocapitalizationType.None
 controllerSearch.searchBar.keyboardType = UIKeyboardType.WebSearch
```

I use iPhone 5s and iPad 3.
 How can I fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you using the simulator? If so you should uncheck your keyboard.

`iOS Simulator-> Hardware-> Keyboard -> Connect Hardware Keyboard`

That could fix your first error:  [similar problems on Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24871532/xcode-ios-8-keyboard-types-not-supported)

#### Update

Google does not allow to search on emoji anymore. [source](http://searchengineland.com/google-finally-drops-emojis-from-search-results-listings-page-223715)

You could disable emoji in iOS to avoid searching with emoji: [ios 8 disable emoji](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25861468/how-to-disable-ios-8-emoji-keyboard)

The second 'fatal error': just catch the nil caused by the emoji

Comment: No, I am not. I am using iPhone 5s and iPad 3

Comment: uisearchbar.text with a smile equals nil.

Comment: First of all you could catch a nil, to avoid the fatal error. Second, what xcode version are you using? I read a lot about beta's and this problem.

Comment: I am using Version 7.0 (7A220). This error is appearing due to the first error is Can't find keyplane that supports type 10 for keyboard iPhone-Portrait-Emoji; because I wrote a smile in searchBar after I get Can't find keyplane that supports type 10 for keyboard iPhone-Portrait-Emoji; and optional is nil.

Comment: Google does not allow to search on emoji anymore [source](http://searchengineland.com/google-finally-drops-emojis-from-search-results-listings-page-223715)

you could disable emoji in ios to avoid searches with emoji [ios 8 disable emoji keyboard](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25861468/how-to-disable-ios-8-emoji-keyboard)

Comment: The connect hardware keyboard suggestion for this bug is outdated and shouldn't be followed anymore - it is just sidestepping the check that throws this error, you'll always get the error on a real world device without a hardware keyboard.