# Ionic/Cordova/Phonegap: Is there a way to disable Emoji-Keyboard on iOS and Android?

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, keyboard, emoji

Is there a way to allow the ASCII-keyboard only, on iOS and Android?
I'm using the Ionic framework.

I'm not able to find any information regarding this question on the internet. I just found [some native solutions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25861468/how-to-disable-ios-8-emoji-keyboard).

Comment: Did you find any solution?

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
- (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string
{        
    if ([textField isFirstResponder])
    {
        if ([[[textField textInputMode] primaryLanguage] isEqualToString:@"emoji"] || ![[textField textInputMode] primaryLanguage])
        {
            return NO;
        }
    }
    return YES;
}
```

for more info see here: [How to disable iOS 8 emoji keyboard?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25861468/how-to-disable-ios-8-emoji-keyboard)[1](http://%20https://github.com/woxtu/NSString-RemoveEmoji).

EDIT :

You can hide emoji from Keyboard using this code:

```
txtField.keyboardType=UIKeyboardTypeASCIICapable;
```

see github code her: [https://github.com/woxtu/NSString-RemoveEmoji](http://%20https://github.com/woxtu/NSString-RemoveEmoji)

Answer (score 0):

i've used this piece of code,to restrict the entries of emoji

```
this.message_text = e.target.value
      .replace(
        /(?:[\u2700\-\u27bf]|(?:\ud83c[\udde6\-\uddff]){2}|[\ud800\-\udbff][\udc00\-\udfff]|[\u0023\-\u0039]\ufe0f?\u20e3|\u3299|\u3297|\u303d|\u3030|\u24c2|\ud83c[\udd70\-\udd71]|\ud83c[\udd7e\-\udd7f]|\ud83c\udd8e|\ud83c[\udd91\-\udd9a]|\ud83c[\udde6\-\uddff]|\ud83c[\ude01\-\ude02]|\ud83c\ude1a|\ud83c\ude2f|\ud83c[\ude32\-\ude3a]|\ud83c[\ude50\-\ude51]|\u203c|\u2049|[\u25aa\-\u25ab]|\u25b6|\u25c0|[\u25fb\-\u25fe]|\u00a9|\u00ae|\u2122|\u2139|\ud83c\udc04|[\u2600\-\u26FF]|\u2b05|\u2b06|\u2b07|\u2b1b|\u2b1c|\u2b50|\u2b55|\u231a|\u231b|\u2328|\u23cf|[\u23e9\-\u23f3]|[\u23f8\-\u23fa]|\ud83c\udccf|\u2934|\u2935|[\u2190\-\u21ff]|[\uE000\-\uF8FF]|\uD83C[\uDF00\-\uDFFF]|\uD83D[\uDC00\-\uDDFF])/g,
        ""
      )
      .replace(
        /[^A-Za-z0-9\w\.,\?""!@#\$%\^&\*\(\)\-_=\+;:<>\/\\\|\}\{\[\]`~\s\']*/g,
        ""
      );


      let regExp = new RegExp('^[A-Za-z0-9?@$,.*%#!=+:&;"`~_ ]+$');
      if (! regExp.test(this.message_text)) {
        e.target.value = this.message_text.slice(0, -1);
      }
```

It disables the emoji from keyboard but i've got one issue let's see whether you guys notice it! if u notice it kindly reply back with a solution for it!