# iOS Webview input box change to emoji keyboard app crash

Tags: ios, uiwebview

I am working with my web team, and I provide a webview to calling their web page.
Inside the webpage there are some input box to fill-in information with user.
When user change the keyboard to emoji. The app crash with

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception
>   'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[NSTaggedPointerString count]:
>   unrecognized selector sent to instance 0xa00000000006e652'

How can I fix it on my side or any suggestion to my web team?

Comment: this [URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25861468/how-to-disable-ios-8-emoji-keyboard) can help you

Comment: I think this is not my case, my keyboard is call by a html input box not a native one

Comment: @Jam were you able to fix this issue?