# Why isEmoji Instance Property Returns true for numbers?

Tags: swift, string, emoji

## Problem

Why **isEmoji** instance property returns true for numbers?

Check the example below:

```
let scalars: [Unicode.Scalar] = ["", "+", "1"]
for s in scalars {
    print(s, "-->", s.properties.isEmoji)
}
```

#### Results

```
//  --> true
// + --> false
// 1 --> true...
```

wait what?

But **why**? The question is **how to** use the isEmoji property for numbers in the right way.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

#### What

If you're not familiar with the isEmoji instance property it's a boolean value indicating whether the scalar has an emoji presentation, and whether or not it is the default.

It's available under iOS 10.2+, iPadOS 10.2+, macOS 10.12.2+, Mac Catalyst 10.2+, tvOS 10.1+, watchOS 3.1.1+, visionOS 1.0+ Beta.

I did a little research after facing this issue and found the answer in [Apple's documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/unicode/scalar/properties/3081577-isemoji).

#### Why

The final result is **true** because the **ASCII digits** have non-default emoji presentations; some platforms render these with an **alternate appearance**.

Because of this behavior, testing **isEmoji** alone on a single scalar is insufficient to determine if a unit of text is rendered as an emoji; a correct test requires inspecting **multiple**
**scalars** in a Character.

In addition to checking whether the base scalar has isEmoji == true, **you must also check its default presentation** (see isEmojiPresentation) and determine whether it is followed by a variation selector that would modify the presentation. This property corresponds to the “Emoji” property in the [Unicode Standard](http://www.unicode.org/versions/latest/).

## Solution

So you can check like the line below:

```
let scalars: [Unicode.Scalar] = ["", "+", "1"]

for s in scalars {
    print(s, "-->", (s.properties.isEmoji && s.properties.isEmojiPresentation))
}
```

### Final Results

```
//  --> true
// + --> false
// 1 --> false
```

Comment: This won't work for `"✈️"` which returns true for `isEmoji`
 and false for `isEmojiPresentation`

Comment: Won't work for those: ▶️3️⃣, too.

Comment: Here's a nice working example from someone on GitHub: https://gist.github.com/krummler/879e1ce942893db3104783d1d0e67b34

Comment: Thank you for sharing but, not %100 works I guess, 
print("".isSingleEmoji) this returns false on Playgrounds, but the expected result is true in the comment.

Comment: The gist linked to in the comment above doesn't account for skin tone modifiers. add a check for  `isEmojiModifier` in line 12 and that example will work