# iOS swift hide emoj icons in keyboard

Tags: ios, swift, iphone

i am trying to hide emoji icons in iPhone default keyboard

```
keyboardtype = .ascicapbale 

func textField(_ textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersIn range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool {

        if textField.isFirstResponder{

            if textField.textInputMode?.primaryLanguage == "emoji"{

                return textField.textInputMode != nil
            }
        }
```

both solution not working for me. any help will appricated

Comment: try adding nameTextField.keyboardType = .asciiCapable in viewdidload
This is not removing the Emoji keyboard?

Comment: When I use it, it disappears Hindi and Emoji Keyboard and keeps European language keyboards

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to disable the emoji keyboard in iOS 7?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24927351/how-to-disable-the-emoji-keyboard-in-ios-7)

Comment: it did not fix it.